# How to Know the current log level using log4net to store in database

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

How to Know the current log level using log4net to store in database in an application.

Answer (score 8):

If you mean the enabled levels then:

```
bool IsDebugEnabled { get; }
bool IsInfoEnabled { get; }
bool IsWarnEnabled { get; }
bool IsErrorEnabled { get; }
bool IsFatalEnabled { get; }
```

if all of them are true then the level would be Debug, if Info and above is enabled then it is info and so ..

you can check like this

```
if(myLogger.IsDebugEnabled)
  return "Debug";
else if(myLogger.IsInfoEnabled)
  return "Info";
else if(myLogger.IsWarnEnabled)
  return "Warn";
else if(myLogger.IsErrorEnabled)
  return "Error";
else if(myLogger.IsFatalEnabled)
  return "Fatal";
else
  return "None";
```

You can also get the specific level by this:

```
((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)mylogger.Logger).Level
```

Comment: I am not getting the current log level using ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)mylogger.Logger).Level

Comment: Are you sure you configured the logger ?

Comment: I want to check the current log level if the log is debug then store the debug information in database.

Comment: It is better to check for myLogger.IsDebugEnabled() and the so, but if you want to check the exact config, then the the line should be working, but make sure that you configured the logger

Comment: loggerDataBaseLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("DataBaseLogger");

Comment: the system showing all log levels are enabled as true.then how can i check the current log level.

Comment: did you configure the logger ? using .Configure() to load config from app config or xml file ?

Comment: this means that it is Debug .. it is ordered  like this
Debug = IsDebugEnabled + IsInfo + IsWarn + IsError + Isfatal
Info = IsInfo + IsWarn + IsError + Isfatal
Warn = IsWarn + IsError + Isfatal
Error =  IsError + Isfatal
Fatal = IsFatal
None = none

Comment: i configured the logger in web.config

Comment: Below are the lines i written in web.config file <logger name="DataBaseLogger">
      <level value="Debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
    </logger>

Comment: If the mylogger.Logger).Level didnt work then use the code above (i edited the answer) to check the levels in order and return the current one

Comment: ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)loggerDataBaseLog.Logger).Level returning true

Comment: It should return the type log4net.Core.Level

Comment: the above edited line returning Name as "DEBUG" Display Name as "DEBUG".is it work for all the log levels? thanks...

Comment: forget it, what about the other method ?
if(myLogger.IsDebugEnabled())
  return "Debug";
else if(myLogger.IsInfoEnabled())
  return "Info";
else if(myLogger.IsWarnEnabled())
  return "Warn";
else if(myLogger.IsErrorEnabled())
  return "Error";
else if(myLogger.IsFatalEnabled())
  return "Fatal";
else
  return "None";

Comment: I am finding that "EffectiveLevel" property is set to what I configured level to be in the config. However, "Level" property is null.

Comment: I'm also having an issue with using ((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)mylogger.Logger).Level. I should mention that all my logging config settings are in a separate config file, and not my main web.config.

In my main web.config file, I am referencing this separate log config file as follows:

<configSections> <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" /></configSections><log4net configSource="App_Data\log4net.config" />

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue like this for anything implementing ILogger in this case you would have a local property called Logger that is an implementation of ILogger.

```
public LogLevel GetLogLevel()
{
    var levels=new []{LogLevel.Critical,  LogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Warning, LogLevel.Information,LogLevel.Debug,LogLevel.Trace};
    foreach (var level in levels)
    {
        if (Logger.IsEnabled(level))
            return level;
    }
    return LogLevel.None;        
}
```

You could also create a extension method in the ILogger namespace so that anywhere you use ILogger you have the functionality.

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
{

    public static class LoggerExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the current log level
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="logger"></param>
        /// <returns>The most restrictive LogLevel that is used</returns>
        public static LogLevel GetLogLevel(this ILogger logger)
        {
            if (logger is null)
            {
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
            }

            var levels=new []{LogLevel.Critical,  LogLevel.Error, LogLevel.Warning, LogLevel.Information,LogLevel.Debug,LogLevel.Trace};
            foreach (var level in levels)
            {
                if (logger.IsEnabled(level))
                    return level;
            }
            return LogLevel.None;        
        }
    }
}
```